# asp.net sqldatasource with postgres select parameters

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, sqldatasource

In Visual Studio I have an asp.net (vb.net) project using a sqldatasource component connecting to a postgres database. This works fine but now I need to provide a parameter to my select statement and I find no solution:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>"
ProviderName="Npgsql"
SelectCommand="SELECT column2 from myTable where column1 = :column1)">
 <SelectParameters>
  <asp:Parameter Name=":column1" Type="String"/>
 </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

When I try to update the scheme I get an

> Error 42601 Syntax error at >>:<<

I also tried using parameter @column1 (instead of :column1, which works for my mssqlserver connections), but then I get

> Error 42883 operator does not exist @ character varying".

Is there a way to use the sqldatasource with postgres sql parameters without programming code behind?

Comment: "without programming code behind"? Why do you say that?

Comment: All solution according postgres sql paramter I saw were code behind solutions. I wanted a solution just for the sqldatasource component.

Comment: Yes, I clearly understood that. What I am asking you is *why* you do not want a code behind solution. Please answer that question.

Comment: Its fast and easy for me within visual studio to define a sqldatasource and bind a gridview (or any other data view) to that datasource without any programming (just the select statement) ... and (edited) being able to test the sqlstatement without running the application or using a seperate tool.

Comment: You're shooting yourself in the foot by avoiding code behind. Web Forms is dying for a good reason. The ASPX paradigm results in terrible software, and people that don't know how to code, and you don't want those people making software. Learn to embrace the code behind and the power that it gives you.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwile I found more or less accidantally the solution, so I give it here if someone else might be interested:
Within the SelectCommdand I use "@column1" as the parameter.
Within the SelectParamter-section the parameter name must be "column1" (without @):

```html
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>"
ProviderName="Npgsql"
SelectCommand="SELECT column2 from myTable where column1 = @column1)">
 <SelectParameters>
  <asp:Parameter Name="column1" Type="String"/>
 </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Its still not possible to perform "update scheme" with the sqldatasource component (still getting error) but now the select statement works fine during runtime, i.e. the gridview based on the sqldatasource shows the selected data as required.